# Align several tikzpictures horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.1pt,draw=black},
every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}
}

\newcommand{\plotWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\plotHeight}{3cm}
\newcommand{\hDist}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[htb]{\hDist}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\plotWidth,height=\plotHeight,ylabel=$u(x)$,xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
                \addplot[smooth] {x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %\caption{Subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[htb]{\hDist}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\plotWidth,height=\plotHeight,xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
                \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %\subcaption{Subcaption}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[htb]{\hDist}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\plotWidth,height=\plotHeight,xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
                \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %\subcaption{Subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}[htb]{\hDist}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\plotWidth,height=\plotHeight,xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
                \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3+x^4};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        %\subcaption{Subcaption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Subcaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

I would like to know how I can align the plots horizontally such that they do not overlap. I tried `\hfil`, `\hfill` and `\hspace{1cm}` to separate the plots which did not work.

Comment: Reduce the plotwidth length, and make hDist longer. If you are not going to add subcaptions, have a look at the groupplots library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to cry for `groupplots`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.1pt,draw=black},
every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}
}

\newcommand{\plotWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\plotHeight}{3cm}
\newcommand{\hDist}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=4 by 1},height=\plotHeight,width=\plotWidth]
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$u(x)$,xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
           \addplot[smooth] {x};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
            \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
             \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3};
        \nextgroupplot[xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
                \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3+x^4};
        \end{groupplot}
      \end{tikzpicture}
        %\subcaption{Subcaption}
    \caption{Subcaption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the current settings the figure is a bit too wide. Options to rectify this include making the individual plots less wide and/or using the setting of the example on p. 456 of the pgfplots manual to use one set of yticks for all plots. Here is a concrete proposal spelling that out.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.1pt,draw=black},
every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}
}

\newcommand{\plotWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\plotHeight}{3cm}
\newcommand{\hDist}{0.03\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=4 by 1, y descriptions at=edge
      left, horizontal sep=\hDist},height=\plotHeight,width=\plotWidth,
      xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$u(x)$]
           \addplot[smooth] {x};
        \nextgroupplot[]
            \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2};
        \nextgroupplot[]
             \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3};
        \nextgroupplot[]
                \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3+x^4};
        \end{groupplot}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A group of plots.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not know whether one can combine "real" captions with group plots. What one can certainly do is to use the title as a replacement of a caption.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.1pt,draw=black},
every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
every axis title/.append style={at={(0.5,-1.1)}}}
\newcommand{\plotWidth}{4cm}
\newcommand{\plotHeight}{3cm}
\newcommand{\hDist}{0.03\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=4 by 1, y descriptions at=edge
      left, horizontal sep=\hDist},height=\plotHeight,width=\plotWidth,
      xlabel=$x$,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,xmax=1]
        \nextgroupplot[ylabel=$u(x)$,title={Left.}]
           \addplot[smooth] {x};
        \nextgroupplot[title={Rather left.}]
            \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2};
        \nextgroupplot[title={Rather right.}]
             \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3};
        \nextgroupplot[title={Right.}]
                \addplot[smooth] {x+x^2+x^3+x^4};
        \end{groupplot}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A group of plots.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a simple way to add subcaptions to each plot?

Comment: @Samuel I have never tried to add a "real" subcaption. You can definitely move the title below the figure. I added an example. Whether or or not one can use a subcaption would IMHO deserve a new question.